# Keeping Login Session in All Pages

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm beginner on PHP. I coded a basic number guess script. Now I want to implement user register and login features. I'm following [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/user-membership-with-php--net-1523) tutorial.

I have `base.php` make database connection:

```
<?php
session_start();

$dbhost = "localhost"; // this will ususally be 'localhost', but can sometimes differ
$dbname = "users"; // the name of the database that you are going to use for this project
$dbuser = "xxx"; // the username that you created, or were given, to access your database
$dbpass = "xxx"; // the password that you created, or were given, to access your database

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
?>
```

I call this file in `login.php` user can login in here or go to register form. After he logged in, play game button appers.

```
<?php include "base.php"; ?>
<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))
{
     ?>

     <h1>Member Area</h1>
     <p>Thanks for logging in! You are <code><?=$_SESSION['Username']?></code> and your email address is <code><?=$_SESSION['EmailAddress']?></code>.</p>

 <form name = "mysecondform" action  = "level1.php" method = "POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="seconddata" value="1">
        <br> <input type= "submit" value = "Start calculator game"><br>
<p> Click <a href="logout.php">here</a> to logout</p>

     <?php
}
elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

    $checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);
        $email = $row['EmailAddress'];

        $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;

        echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
        echo "<form name = \"mysecondform\" action  = \"level1.php\" method = \"POST\">";
        echo " <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"seconddata\" value=\"1\">";
        echo "<br> <input type= \"submit\" value = \"Start calculator game\">";

    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"login.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";
    }
}
else
{
    //some codes about registration
}
?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, `level1.php` checks if the value is correct (well I should do this with user login session but i can't do it yet)

```
<?php
if ($_POST["seconddata"] == "1"){

echo "<html><head><title>Calculator Game From 1998</title></head><body>";
echo "<h1>Please Guess The Answer-Level1</h1>";
echo "<form name = \"myfirstform\" action  = \"formprocess.php\" method = \"POST\">";
echo "Enter Integer Between 1-3<br>";
echo "<input type = \"text\" name = \"firstdata\">";
echo "<br> <input type= \"submit\" value = \"submit\">";
echo "</form>";
echo "</body></html>";
}
else
echo "Please <a href='login.php'>login</a>"
?>
```

It sends user input to `formprocess.php` file in order to check if the answer is correct. If it's correct, player can go to second level.

```
<?php include "base.php"; ?>
<?php
/*
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['wins']) || !isset($_SESSION['losses'])) {
    $_SESSION['wins'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['losses'] = 0;
}
*/
$random = rand(1, 3);

echo "<html><head><title>Answer-Level1</title></head><body>";
if ($_POST["firstdata"] == $random){
$_SESSION['wins']++; 
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET win= win + 1 WHERE Username = '".$username."'");
 echo "<h1><font color=\"green\">Congrulations!</h1></font><br>";
echo "<img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flatastic-2/512/success-icon.png' width='100' height='100'></img>";
 echo "<h2>Answer was: </h2>";

  echo $random;
echo "<br>";
//echo "<p>You've won {$_SESSION['wins']} games and lost {$_SESSION['losses']}.</p>";
echo "<br>";  
echo "<form name = \"mysecondform\" action  = \"level2.php\" method = \"POST\">";
echo " <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"seconddata\" value=\"1\">";
echo "<br> <input type= \"submit\" value = \"Go to Level2\">";
$win++;
}
else{
$_SESSION['losses']++;
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET lost= lost + 1 WHERE Username = '".$username."'");
echo "<h1><font color=\"red\">Nope wrong answer</h1></font><br>";
echo "<img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/D/Y/s/v/C/m/wrong-hi.png' width='100' height='100'></img>";
 echo "<h2>Answer was: </h2>";
  echo $random;
echo "<br>";
//echo "<p>You've won {$_SESSION['wins']} games and lost {$_SESSION['losses']}.</p>";
echo "<br>";  
echo "<a href=\"level1.php\">try again</a>";

}  
echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

(I commented out session codes. It's old version, I have to keep win,lost track on database) Well the problem is

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET win= win + 1 WHERE Username = '".$username."'");
```

this query doesn't change the value. I changed `.$username.` with specific username it works. So how can I keep login session on this page (on every pages)

Sorry for long post.

Comment: You have to define `$username` in your `formprocess.php`.

Comment: You are storing the username in the session if login is successful, so you just need to read it back again in another page, after you've started the session. (Btw, MD5 is no longer safe to store passwords with, use `password_hash()` instead please. Tutsplus should also be updating that material to use a new library - the one you/they are using is deprecated).

Comment: @halfer how can i read it back again?

Comment: Test if it exists with `isset($_SESSION['Username'])` and then if so, do `$username = $_SESSION['Username'];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an undefined variable - **$username**. What you should use is: **$_SESSION['username']**

Replace

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET win= win + 1 WHERE Username = '".$username."'");
```

With

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET win= win + 1 WHERE Username = '".mysql_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])."'");
```

**mysql_escape_string** is used to escape any character that conflicts with the mysql syntax and is used for security reasons. Read more about it here: [PHP: mysql_escape_string - Manual](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.mysql-escape-string.php)

Comment: still not working edit: it's working. you wrote username instead of Username

Comment: @JayGatsby: minor case issues are your job to fix. Consider solutions here as clues to assist you, not things that can be typed in verbatim `:)`.

Comment: Actually you have to use $_SESSION['Username'] with capital "U" not $_SESSION['username'] my bad